# SQL - retrieving related records separately vs one join

Tags: sql, postgresql, rest, foreign-keys

I have an application that is using a REST API. That rest api fetches data from a SQL database with two tables A and B. Table B has a foreign key to table A.

What I want is from the application: get certain Bs, and also, get all related records of A; those that B has foreign key to.

Currently, I made an API to retrieve those certain Bs. But it only returns the Bs. I was planning to:

1. From the application, retrieve certain Bs, and after that, make a second rest api call to retrieve all the related As. Then I need to map those Bs to As in the application.

On the REST point of view that seems ok. But I was wondering that would it be better to just do a single rest api call, that would fetch all the Bs, and along with those also the related As? I guess this would require doing some INNER JOINs on the SQL table?

Also, that second option doesn't seem as good from the REST point of view. Because there's no such entity as B with A. There are only As and Bs. And I want to make clear REST api to fetch entities.

So which one would be the better solution in my case? I'm using POSTGRESQL as my database. If you need any more info about the case (example how many records etc.. just ask, I can think about them)

EDITS:

My 2 options are:

1. With 2 SQL queries:
   `SELECT * FROM table_B WHERE id = ?` & `SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE id IN (id_1, id_2, id_3, ...)` This requires 2 API calls, where the first will initiate the first sql query, and second will initiate the second sql query
2. With 1 SQL query:

   `select b.*, a.*
   from b join
    a
    on b.? = a.?
   where b.? in (?, ?, ?, . . .);`

   This will only require 1 API call, 1 SQL query. But the tradeoff is, that I need to do sql join + it's not as RESTfull regarding recourses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve information from "A" and "B" for certain "B" records and they are related, then the typical solution would be:

```
select b.*, a.*
from b join
     a
     on b.? = a.?
where b.? in (?, ?, ?, . . .);
```

The question marks are represent places where you should put in information that is not in your question.

This returns the information from "A" and "B" in a single row.  For most applications this is good.  And it does so with only a single database call.

Under some limited circumstances, it might be better to do multiple queries.  Remember that there is overhead for each query -- one reason why it is better to let the database do the work.  But, if the columns in "B" are really wide, you may not want to duplicate them for every record in "A".

Comment: Yeah but I would only need to do 2 queries in the separate option: 1. for fetching all Bs, and then one query which will fetch all As related to Bs. I think you can make that second query by just using one query. So total 2 queries hmm... Anyways, good answer, thanks!

Comment: Which two queries? Please can you write those queries you are using in Structured Query Language instead of English?

Comment: Wrote those in SQL to the beginning question post